# Cancel all async tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation-token

Is it possible to cancel all async methods, without knowing what is currently running?

For example I have several classes that may run async tasks:

```
class Class1
{
    public async void SomeTask()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // Doing some job
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public async void ContinuouslyTask()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            // Doing some job on background
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want turn off every async task, before I will logout:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var c1 = new Class1();
        var c2 = new Class2();

        c1.SomeTask();
        c2.ContinuouslyTask(); 

        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }

        p.Logout();
    }

    private void Logout()
    {
        // Cancel all async tasks

        // And do logout work
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, without saving tasks into query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically extending @FrankFajardo answer to provide a concrete example.
When you pass in a `CancellationToken`, you also need to monitor it for any cancellation request from the outside. It will look like this:

```
class Class1
{
    public async Task SomeTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
            // Doing some job
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public async Task ContinuouslyTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Doing some job on background
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And now when you want to cancel it, you simply add `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` call to your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Program();
    var c1 = new Class1();
    var c2 = new Class2();

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var someTask = c1.SomeTask(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    var continuousTask = c2.ContinuouslyTask(cancellationTokenSource.Token); 

    while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }

    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    Task.WaitAll(someTask, continuousTask);

    p.Logout();
}
```

Note I'm using `Task.WaitAll` only because this is a console application where `Main` can't be async. Otherwise, use `Task.WhenAll` which returns an awaitable `Task`.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should make your `c1.SomeTask()` and `c2.ContinuouslyTask()` accept cancellation tokens, and check for that token to see if the reques is being cancelled, and end abruptly if so.

Then in your `Program.Main()`, it should create a CancellationTokenSource and pass the CancellationTokenSource.Token to the 2 async method it calls. This CancellationTokenSource should be accessible to the `Program.Logout()` so that it can issue the cancellation on logout. See example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token.aspx)

NOTE: It is generally advised that async methods return Tasks, instead of void. Also, it is a convention that async methods are named xxxAsync (eg. DoWorkAsync).